# How can i get the sum of the values between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

my query is

```
select 
    ir.ProductId,
    sum(ir.IssueQuantity) as 'Quantity',
    p.ProductName,
    ir.IssueDate,
    ir.ReturnDate
from Product.IssueReturn ir 
join Company.Product p on p.ProductId=ir.ProductId
group by ir.ProductId,p.ProductName,ir.IssueDate,ir.ReturnDate
```

Comment: i want to get the sum of the hemp bags in one row

Comment: Specify your expected result

Comment: ProductId   Quantity    ProductName        IssueDate  ReturnDate
----------- ----------- ----------------- ----------                       ----------
7           20          Hemp Bag           2016-11-23      2016-11-24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    ProductId ,  PrdName , 
    SUM(IssueQuantity) IssueQuantity ,
    MIN(IssueDate) IssueDate,MAX(ReturnDATE) ReturnDATE 
FROM Table1 join Table2 on ProductId = ProductId 
GROUP BY ProductId , PrdName
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove date field column in selection.

```
        select ir.ProductId,sum(ir.IssueQuantity)as 'Quantity',p.ProductName
        --,ir.IssueDate,ir.ReturnDate

        from Product.IssueReturn ir join Company.Product p on p.ProductId=ir.ProductId

        group by ir.ProductId,p.ProductName
        --,ir.IssueDate,ir.ReturnDate
```

Comment: It worked.
Thank-you for your help but what if i want the date field ?

Comment: as per your result. You have 2 records of 'Hamps' with different ReturnDate. but other ProductId have same retrun date.
if You want single result then you can use minimun ReturnDate or maximum ReturnDate.

Comment: plz check this . who first added answer here. then vot up.

Comment: the answer which i wanted i got from the other answer
Sorry and thankyou